# SQL Exclusion in the select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a SQL Server query which is processing several thousands of rows. However the script runs fine, but I need to apply to just one of the select statements a criteria but not have it affect the rest of the results.

```
Select
    Count ([key]) as KEYCOUNT, 
    Round (AVG ([AGE]),2) as AGE, 
    Round (AVG ([LENGTH]),2) as Length_X,
    Round (AVG ([Duration]),2) as DUR_Y,
from 
    [dbo].[XYZ]
where 
    [FLAG] = 1  and STAT = 3
```

The select I need to affect is `Round (AVG ([LENGTH]),2) as Length_X`, which I need to calculate as the average of only those lengths which are greater than 0, basically excluding all 0 (zeros)

Help much appreciated

Cheers

Comment: if your 0s are actually representing values which should be ignored (i.e 0 is not a valid value to be considered as part of the average), shouldn't they be NULL instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression as the parameter of that `AVG` function:

```
Round(AVG(case when [LENGTH] > 0 then [LENGTH] end), 2) as Length_X,
```

This way all 0 values will be ignored by the `AVG`, while all other expressions in your query won't be affected.

Comment: Thanks for this. Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

*which I need to calculate as the average of only those lengths which are greater than 0, basically excluding all 0 (zeros)*

Which is just sum(Length) / sum(case Length when 0 then 0 else 1 end) with the appropriate casting if needed. E.g.

```
set nocount on; 
with cte as (select * from (values  (0), (1), (2), (1), (0), (0)) as l(length))
select avg(cast(length as float)) as avg1, 
sum(cast(length as float)) / sum(case length when 0 then 0 else 1 end) as avg2 
from cte; 

with cte as (select * from (values  (1), (2), (1) ) as l(length))
select avg(cast(length as float)) as avg1, 
sum(cast(length as float)) / sum(case length when 0 then 0 else 1 end) as avg2 
from cte;
```

Notice the case condition. I used "not zero", you said "greater than zero". You choose.